To get the highest value after the hyphen (-) from the list
I have below data in one file and I want to print only highest value after the hyphen (-) from the list
input:
4.1-1
4.1
4.0-2
4.0-1
4.0
3.14-2
3.14-1
3.14
3.13.-1
3.13
3.12
3.11-2
3.11-1
3.11

output should be
4.1-1
4.0-2
3.14-2
3.13.-1
3.12
3.11-2

I tried with below
awk -F'-' '/-/{print $2}' <<EOF | sort -n | tail -n 1
4.1-1
4.1
4.0-2
4.0-1
4.0
3.14-2
3.14-1
3.14
EOF

its not giving be desire output, basically i want unique tag and tag with hyphen highest value
3.13-1
3.13
3.12
3.11-2
3.11-1
3.11

so it should print only 3.13-1 (it is highest value from 3.13, since 3.12 is unique it should print and from 3.11-2 (because it is highest from 3.11)  like below
3.13-1
3.12
3.11-2

can you please guide how I can achieve thin in Unix
Regards

you mean "the line with the highest value ..."? And apparently the part before the dash also counts somehow, but you're not saying that.

why isn't 3.13 printed while 3.12 is? Neither has a corresponding line with a dash.

are we supposed to treat 3.13 and 3.13. as being the same?

Firstly I apologize for my poor English and explanation , the solution is working as expected.

If the input is sorted like that, with the "highest" value for each initial (before the dash) part first, then this can be reduced to just printing the line if the initial part is different from the last line:
% awk -F- '$1 != last {last = $1; print}' < nums
4.1-1
4.0-2
3.14-2
3.13.-1
3.13
3.12
3.11-2

(I can't tell from your description why 3.13 should be excluded from the output, it's the only one with that initial part given 3.13.-1 has an extra dot.)
If that's not the case, you could collect the highest second parts and corresponding full line and print them in the end. This may mix out the output order due to how arrays work in AWK, so you'll need to sort it after:
% awk -F- '!($1 in val) || $2 > val[$1] { val[$1] = $2; line[$1] = $0; }
           END { for(i in line) print line[i] }
          ' < nums |sort -rV
4.1-1
4.0-2
3.14-2
3.13.-1
3.13
3.12
3.11-2


@ikkachu , Solution is working as expected, thanks for educating me

There is a "famous" AWK idiom for selecting lines only where a field value only appears for the first time.
awk -F- '!seen[$1]++' file


seen is an associative array, keyed by the value of the first hyphen-separated field.
seen[$1]++ uses the post-increment operator: the first time that 4.1 appears, seen[$1]++ evaluates to 0; the second time, to 1; etc.
then the ! operator negates that: 0 becomes "true"; any other numeric value becomes "false"
then the default action, print, happens for lines where !seen[$1]++ is "true"

If the file is not already sorted, and you have GNU sort, you can use the -V "version sort" option
sort -V -r file | awk -F- '!seen[$1]++'


With GNU sort or compatible:
$ <your-file sort -t- -k2rn | sort -sut- -k1,1rg
4.1-1
4.0-2
3.14-2
3.13.-1
3.12
3.11-2

